# Overload == in Groovy to not return boolean

Tags: groovy, operator-overloading, dsl

I'm currently developing a DSL using Groovy for a math related API written in Java.

The `Expression` class has a method with the following signature:

`public Constraint equals(Expression that)`

We want to define a constraint, which will only be evaluated later.

Is it possible to override `==` using our `equals` implementation so that it doesn't return `boolean` but `Constraint`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as far as I know, it is not possible...

The `==` operator at some point ends up in [`DefaultTypeTransformation.java::compareEqual`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java#L600) which returns `boolean`, so even if you do:

```
class Yay {}

class Woo {
    String equals(Yay y) {
        'hello'
    }
}

println new Woo() == new Yay()
```

You will get the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.compareEqual(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:641)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:684)
    at ConsoleScript3.run(ConsoleScript3:9)
```

It will work with `a.equals(b)`, but not `a == b`

Comment: Should this be requested as a feature? This seems like a reasonable use-case in DSLs.